# How to prevent Subversion from doing automatic merges and apply changes manually

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I found this solution (shown below) for: **How to prevent Subversion from doing automatic merges?** It appears many times on the Internet and also here at stackoverflow.

> Some people don't like the fact that Subversion merges changes from others with their own local working copy changes automatically on update. Here's how to force those files into a conflicted state so you can merge manually at your convenience.
>
> In TortoiseSVN->Settings->Subversion configuration file, click on the edit button.
>   Change the [helpers] section by adding diff-cmd = "C:\false.bat" diff3-cmd = "C:\false.bat" (note the double backslash)
>       Create the file C:\false.bat which contains two lines

```
    @type %9
    @exit 1
```

> This effectively makes auto-merge fail every time, forcing the file into conflict.
>
> The reason for the curious 'type %9' line is that the diff3-cmd sends the merged output to stdout. Subversion then takes this and overwrites your local file with the merge results. Adding this line avoids getting an empty local file.

But it doesn't seem to work because it is impossible to manually correct conflicts. The tortoisesvn tool used for editing conflicts, despite it enables editing these conflists, it doesn't write down the edited file correctly. The changes I make aren't respected. The old file is completely overwriten with a new one.

These files are created: index2.php.merge-left.r152, index2.php.merge-right.r157, index2.php.working and contain the oryginal content without additional changes like addtional strings like this one '>>>>' that indicate what changes were made.

How to correctly apply changes to the found conflicts? 
Or this solution is for the conflicts visualisation only?

Answer (score 0):

I think IntelliJ is the best SVN client there is.  It gives me the chance to visually inspect both files whenever there's a conflict and choose the bits I want to keep and discard.

I don't see any way to automate judgement.  If two developers have a conflict, the only way to resolve it is to talk and come to a consensus.